# How to type annotate List parameter with specific values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I have a parameter that is a list of strings. However, I want to only allow certain strings, let's say "hello" and "world". How can I correctly annotate the variable?

Here is an example:

```py
def foo(bar: List[str]):
    assert all(b in ["hello", "world"])
```

I know that I can use `Literal`, but AFAIK this only works for single values. I.e. `Literal["hello", "world"]` would allow `bar` to be a string of the value of either "hello" or "world". But how does this work for lists?

Comment: `List[Literal["hello", "world"]]`?

Comment: you can use `typing` module in python

Comment: Note, though, that `[x]` does not have type `List[Literal[...]]` unless `x` itself has type `Literal[...]`.

Answer (score -1):

`enum` module of Python can help you. I have modified your code as below -

```
from typing import List
from enum import Enum

class HelloWorld(Enum):
    _hello = "hello"
    _world = "world"

def foo(bar: List[HelloWorld]):
    assert all(b in [HelloWorld._hello, HelloWorld._world] for b in bar)
```

Please find this references for [typing Union](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/it/python-types/#__tabbed_4_2) and [enum](https://realpython.com/python-enum/#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20enum%20module%20provides%20the,related%20constants%20as%20enum%20members.)

Comment: `Union["hello", "world']` is not a subtype of `str` consisting only of those two strings. It's a pair of forward references to types named `hello` and `world`.

Comment: then can't I use `Union[str, str]`

Comment: No, that's equivalent to `str`.

Comment: Then we can use  Enum

Comment: Sure, if you change the function to accept values of the enumerated type instead of `str` values.

Comment: (Even if you subclass `StrEnum`, values of that type can be used where a `str` is expected, but not vice versa.)